# Conversion of javascript to jquery (getelementbyid, tagname, innertext, innerhtml)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code written in javascript n when I am trying to convert in jQuery I am getting error.

```
    var holder = document.getElementById('filedetails')
    , rows = holder.getElementsByTagName('tr')
setSuccess = function(filename) {
      if (holder != null) {
        for (i = 0, j = rows.length; i < j; ++i) {
          cells = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
          if (cells[0].innerText == filename && cells[3].innerText != "error!") {
            cells[3].innerHTML = "<a href='#' class='file-delete ss-delete no-click'></a>";
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I tried

```
var holder = $('#filedetails"), 
    rows = $('#filedetails tr")
```

I am not sure what to do with innertext and innerhtml.

```
<div data-behavior="delete-process" id="holder">
                <table>
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th class="medium-5">Name</th>
                      <th class="medium-3">Size</th>
                      <th class="medium-3">Type</th>
                      <th class="medium-1"></th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody id="filedetails">
<tr data-filesize="1.4" data-filename="Sample Image.jpg">
<td><strong>Sample_Image</strong></td>
<td class="nodesize">1.4 MB</td>
<td>JPG</td>
<td class="file-loading"><a href="#" class="file-delete ss-delete"></a></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<div class="margin bottom large text-center drag-desc">drag and drop files here.</div>
              </div>
```

Comment: Simple – `jQuery.text()` and `jQuery.html()`

Comment: For `innerText`: use `$('selector').text()` - for `innerHTML`: use `$('selector').html()`

Comment: There are pretty easily searched for: "jquery equivalent of innerhtml" and "jquery equivalent of innertext" both return the correct answer.

Comment: how about cells = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');

Comment: Let us know what is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a "jqueryized" version of your code

```
var holder = $('#filedetails'),
  rows = holder.find('tr');
var setSuccess = function(filename) {
  rows.each(function() {
    var cells = $(this).find('td');
    if (cells.eq(0).text() == filename && cells.eq(3).text() != "error!") {
      cells.eq(3).html("<a href='#' class='file-delete ss-delete no-click'></a>");
    }
  });
};
setSuccess("Sample_Image");
```

Alternate that just uses the rows:

```
var  rows = $('#filedetails').find('tr');
var setSuccess = function(filename,useme) {
  useme.each(function() {
    var cells = $(this).find('td');
    if (cells.eq(0).text() == filename && cells.eq(3).text() != "error!") {
      cells.eq(3).html("<a href='#' class='file-delete ss-delete no-click'>freebeer</a>");
    }
  });
};
setSuccess("Sample_Image", rows);
```

To NOT use a positional table element, use a class and filter by that within  the `TD` cells as here: This assumes one use of a class per row.

```
var rows = $('#filedetails').find('tr');
var setSuccess = function(filename, useme) {
  useme.each(function() {
    var cells = $(this).find('td');
    if (cells.filter('.file-name').text() == filename
          && cells.filter('.file-loading').text() != "error!") {
      cells.filter('.file-loading')
        .html("<a href='#' class='file-delete ss-delete no-click'>noclick</a>");
    }
  });
};
setSuccess("Sample_Image", rows);
```

Fiddl https://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/0fx2jms7/2/

Comment: fileDetails.push({ KEY: cells[0].innerText + "." + cells[2].innerText , FILENAME: cells[0].innerText , SIZE: parseFloat(cells[1].innerHTML.replace(' MB', '')) , EXT: cells[2].innerText , STATUS: fileStatus , TAG: cells[3].outerHTML }); 


when i am trying to use class names instead of cells[0] cells[1]... its push to all the existing entries as well, the same data

Comment: Not sure exactly how your comment relates to my answer here, can you elaborate?  Here is a sample fiddle where I tested this https://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/0fx2jms7/1/

Comment: what i m trying to do here is instead of using cells count i wanted to use css class or any other property in case if there is any change in cell positioning code won't break

Comment: Easy, use filter - I added an example for that.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following code snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
          var holder = $("#filedetails")
            , rows = holder.find('tr');
        var rowsLength=rows.Length;

        var setSuccess = function(filename) {
              if (holder != null) {
                var j=rows.length;
           for (var i=0; i < j; ++i) {
                 var cells = $(rows[i]).find('td');
             var filename=$('.filename');
             var file=$('.file');

                  if (filename.text() == filename && file.text() != "error!") 
                  {

                    var aElement=$("<a/>");
                    aElement.href="#";
                    aElement.class="file-delete ss-delete no-click";

                    file.html(aElement);
                  }
                }
              }
        }


    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-behavior="delete-process" id="holder">
                <table>
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th class="medium-5">Name</th>
                      <th class="medium-3">Size</th>
                      <th class="medium-3">Type</th>
                      <th class="medium-1"></th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody id="filedetails">
<tr data-filesize="1.4" data-filename="Sample Image.jpg">
<td class="filename"><strong>Sample_Image</strong></td>
<td class="nodesize">1.4 MB</td>
<td>JPG</td>
<td class="file-loading file"><a href="#" class="file-delete ss-delete"></a></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<div class="margin bottom large text-center drag-desc">drag and drop files here.</div>
              </div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks but var cells = rows[i].find('td'); throwing an error

Comment: =Uncaught TypeError: rows[i].find is not a function(…)

Comment: Hey can you add the markup here..it will be helpful to solve

Comment: modified hope this helps

Comment: looks like still not able to get the values in var cells. i have added markup

Comment: instead of cells[0], cells[3] can i use classes or any other alternative as code might fail in case of any change in cell positioning

Comment: yes that would be perfect add specific classes to these cells and check for that in the code